# can we stop evrencoskun TableView vertical scrolling in android?

Tags: android, tableview

```
 mTableView.setShadowColor(0);
 mTableView.setShowVerticalSeparators(false);
```

Do we have any attribute to stop vertical scrolling in TableView. Like shown above.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't get what you mean actually, why do you want to disable the scroll feature?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you require something like this. But you can do it setting custom layoutManager for both `CellRecyclerView` and `RowHeaderRecyclerView`.

Create your own layout manager

```
    MyCellLayoutManager extends CellLayoutManager{
    ...

     @Override
     public boolean canScrollVertically() {
      return false;
     }
    }
```

For RowHeader

```
   MyRowHeaderLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager{
    MyRowHeaderLayoutManager(Context context){
     super(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    }
    ...

     @Override
     public boolean canScrollVertically() {
      return false;
     }
    }
```

And Set them to the related RecyclerViews

```
tableView.getCellRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(new MyCellLayoutManager());
tableView.getRowHeaderRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(new MyRowHeaderLayoutManager());
```